# Name on each line

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to make some sort of "aliaslist" for a game.

I've gotten so far where a user connects, the code check if their "aliaslist" file exist, it it doesn't it'll create one.

Once its created, their playername gets saved to that file, However, if they reconnect it will be `namename`

I want to achieve it to have a name on each line like:

```
name
name
```

I currently have this code, and was wondering what I am doing wrong. Note, its the q3engine.

```
if(!isBot) {
            file = va("aliaslist/%s", onlyip);
            trap_FS_FOpenFile( file, &f, FS_APPEND_TEXT );

            if ( !f ) {
                trap_FS_FOpenFile( file, &f, FS_WRITE_TEXT );
            }

            else {
                int len;
                len = strlen(client->pers.netname);
                trap_FS_Write(va("%s \n", client->pers.netname), len, f);
                trap_FS_FCloseFile( f );
            }
        }
```

Comment: you don't write anything on the not exists (!f) case

Comment: trap_FS_FOpenFile( file, &f, FS_WRITE_TEXT );

Does create the file ;) If i connect & disconnect I check the file and the names are in there, just not 1 line per name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only write `strlen(client->pers.netname)` number of characters to the file in your `trap_FS_Write`.

To write the space and the newline as well:

```
trap_FS_Write(va("%s \n", client->pers.netname), len + 2, f);
```

(Notice the `+ 2`)

Comment: Totally forgot about the len var, thanks dude! It's fixed now =)